# How to count key values in a HashMap

Tags: java

I basically am writing this for a game and i'm stuck..

We basically have 2 teams

```
public enum TeamType {
   TEAM_ONE,
   TEAM_TWO;
}

private Optional<TeamType> team;
```

and a hashmap

```
private Map<TeamType, Player> teamPlayers = new HashMap<>();
```

how would we count the amount of players within a team type? 
(Returning a numeric value)

```
teamPlayers.get(TeamType.ZAMORAK).size();
```

is not possible.

Comment: A `Map<TeamType, Player>` is not suited for this. A `MultiMap<TeamType, Player>` is.

Comment: The number of values per key is one, and the number of values equals the number of keys, which is given by `Map.size()`. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: EJP Read the question again, it makes perfect sense. I want to return a numerical value of the players in a team. Not of the whole map. My question has been answered by @Weston

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should be using `EnumMap` if `TeamType` is an enum. However, this seems like a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Don't (completely) change your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were a list of players:

```
private Map<TeamType, List<Player>> teamPlayers = new HashMap<>();
```

This would work:

```
teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TEAM_ONE).size();
```

Of course you'd need to initialize an empty player list:

```
teamPlayers.put(TeamType.TEAM_ONE, new ArrayList<Player>());
teamPlayers.put(TeamType.TEAM_TWO, new ArrayList<Player>());
```

Then to add players to a team:

```
teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TEAM_ONE).add(new Player());
```

Answer (score 1):

From Java's documentation, [HashMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) are not able to be used with multiple values per key.  You should carefully look at what your current code is doing.  Sotirios suggested a MultiHashMap, which would work for people with similar issues, but because you have only two teams you may want to consider another option.

If you use a MultiHashMap, `teamPlayers.get(TeamType.ZAMORAK).size();`
will return the collection of players on Team ZAMORAK's size.