# Counting occurrences of values of items inside a List within a Hash<String,List<String>>

Tags: java, list, hash, hashmap, counting

I have a hash structure `hash_feat <String, List<String>>` where my **keys** are **Years** and the **values** list inside has a list of different terms.

I already have my hash has in a way that all items from a specific **key** are in the same list for that key, like:

`<1997> <A,B,C,A,A,A,B,C,C,E>
 <2003> <C,C,C,A,B,A,D,D,D,A>
 <2004> <A,C,C,X,X,A,K,T,T,T>`

I would like to have for each item a counting. For 1997 A:4, B:2, C:3, E:1  so on and so forth for the other **keys**.

I am trying to come up with this to use this "counting" to later display in a figure where I can visualize the highest counts for each item in a graph. Probably this is not the smartest way, so any advice here would be welcome as well.The idea is to have the quantity of each item in my list so I can manipulate/use in other methods.

Anyone have a good advice to do this in a smart way?

Comment: [Guava Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) is a nice tool to count things. See also *utils* in `Multisets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a "simple" solution for Java 8:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, Map<String, Long>> props =
  map.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
    e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(groupingBy(String::toString, counting()))));
```

This will give you a Map of years to a Map of keys to counts.

Comment: I will try it right now and let you know about the result

Comment: Almost worked, it provides a count for each "term" by year, but all of them with value 1.
I made a test repeating a term into my hash the result was the following
`1997 {Neurosciences; Physiology; Multidisciplinary Sciences=1, Multidisciplinary Sciences=1} `

I don't know why it did not count properly the first items though @Tassos Bassoukos

Comment: Found an issue.
For some reason if I have more than one item in my list it does not count properly like:
`<1997> <banana, apples; tea, soup; banana>`
It considers the whole item between ";" as one item in the list. 
Although banana and apples are in the same list, they should be considered two words for 1997 and add +1 when read banana again, but it is considering the whole position in the list as one single item, doesn't matter how many words there are inside.

Comment: Then you're not splitting the data properly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a data structure in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) called [`BagMultimap`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/bag/BagMultimap.html) that would would work well with your use case.  Here is how to leverage [`MutableBagMultimap`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/bag/MutableBagMultimap.html) with your example data.

```
MutableBagMultimap<String, String> multimap = Multimaps.mutable.bag.empty();
multimap.putAll("1997", Lists.mutable.with("A","B","C","A","A","A","B","C","C","E"));
multimap.putAll("2003", Lists.mutable.with("C","C","C","A","B","A","D","D","D","A"));
multimap.putAll("2004", Lists.mutable.with("A","C","C","X","X","A","K","T","T","T"));

Assert.assertEquals(4, multimap.get("1997").occurrencesOf("A"));
Assert.assertEquals(2, multimap.get("1997").occurrencesOf("B"));
Assert.assertEquals(3, multimap.get("1997").occurrencesOf("C"));
Assert.assertEquals(1, multimap.get("1997").occurrencesOf("E"));
```

You can output the multimap simply using `forEachKeyMultivalues` and `toStringOfItemToCount`.

```
multimap.forEachKeyMultiValues((key, values) ->
    System.out.println("<" + key + "> " + ((Bag<String>)values).toStringOfItemToCount()));
```

This code displays the following:

```
<1997> {E=1, A=4, B=2, C=3}
<2004> {T=3, A=2, C=2, X=2, K=1}
<2003> {D=3, A=3, B=1, C=3}
```

Or you can write the following using `forEachWithOccurrences` in order to control the output.

```
multimap.forEachKey(key -> {
    System.out.print(key + " ");
    multimap.get(key).forEachWithOccurrences((value, occurrences) ->
        System.out.print(value + ":" + occurrences + " "));
    System.out.println();
});
```

This code displays the following:

```
1997 E:1 A:4 B:2 C:3 
2004 T:3 A:2 C:2 X:2 K:1 
2003 D:3 A:3 B:1 C:3
```

Lastly, you can use `topOccurrences` if you'd like the output ordered from greatest occurrences to least.

```
multimap.forEachKey(key -> {
    System.out.print(key + " ");
    MutableBag<String> bag = multimap.get(key);
    bag.topOccurrences(bag.sizeDistinct())
        .each(pair ->
            System.out.print(pair.getOne() + ":" + pair.getTwo() + " "));
    System.out.println();
});
```

This code displays the following:

```
1997 A:4 C:3 B:2 E:1 
2004 T:3 A:2 C:2 X:2 K:1 
2003 D:3 A:3 C:3 B:1
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: It seems interesting ! The problem is that these "A", "B", and etc are some hundreds, so to count each one of them manually wouldn't be an option.
Is there any way to recover each of these values and count them directly ?

Comment: You have a few options.  It really depends on how you want to manipulate the data.  You can call toStringOfItemToCount(), forEachWithOccurrences() or topOccurrences()  on each Bag.  I'll give you an example of each.  You can also create the BagMultimap structure by using a simple groupBy, ,

Comment: Nice !
I found an issue, when I'm storing my data into the hash :(
It stores a "," every time I found a new occurrence for that same key and separates it. The thing is that the record itself uses ";" to multiple values for that field.

I might have to take a step back and work my arraylist before  plugin into  my hash. Really appreciate your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Hope currently you have something like :

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

So you can  iterate very through all the keys and get count for each key as below:

```
for (List<String> values : map.values()){
    System.out.println(values.size());
}
```

If you need the count of each type within key then you have to check type using values.get() and count each type.

Comment: I have something exactly like this, as you posted.
Hum, interesting I thought this would give the size of the whole list.

Let me try this :-)

Comment: If this is not working you can refer one more similar question where the answer involved type defined as enum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486532/how-to-count-key-values-in-a-hashmap

Comment: as I thought, this will give me the size of every list for each "key", but does not tell me how many items I have for each occurrence.

Comment: The problem is that for each "letter" in my example I need to know its repetitions.
The code you provide worked perfectly, but for the size of each list regarding each key.